# Setting the correct index for a combobbx item

Tags: c#, winforms

There are objects that have properties like  OrderNanme, OrderCode, and many other properties that currently I am inserting them in a HashSet ( they are unique, so using  a "set" is find in my scenario).

Then somewhere else in the code I am enumaritng thortugh this HashSet and adding the OrderName of these objects to a combobx so users can see the names in the combobbx.

Now I also have a OrderCode that if it matches any of the order codes in the those HashSet Items, then I want the Default Text of the Combobx to be set on that order, of course we arer still populating the whole items in the combobx... Is there a way I can do it at one shot? I am thinking I need to have another foreach that goes and finds where is that item and set its index to be the selected index for the combbox but is there a shorter way?

```
double defaultOrder = GiveMeDefaulyOrder() ; // ok so some order number we have here.

foreach(CustomerOrderClass item in cntrlr.ThatHashSet)
{
    comboBox.Item.Add( item.OrderName)
}

//  Now do I need another foreach to just go and find that defaultOrder and set its defaultIndex...but is there a shorter way for this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the DataSource of the combobox to bind a simple HashSet as an example.
This code requires the use of some Linq expressions, but doesn't require a loop to add Order items to the combobox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    HashSet<Order> list = new HashSet<Order>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "OrderName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "OrderNum";
        comboBox1.DataSource = list.ToArray<Order>();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        // Load some sample data
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            Order o = new Order(){OrderName = "Name" + x, OrderNum = x};
            list.Add(o);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Select the item with order number = 4 
        var x = list.Where<Order>(o => o.OrderNum == 4).FirstOrDefault<Order>();
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = x;

    }
}

public class Order
{
    public string OrderName;
    public int OrderNum;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.OrderName;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect. Worked. Just one question for code improvment: you are hard coding the name of properties of the class we want to assign to DisplayMember and ValueMember like "OrderName" ... is there is better way that we can also avoid hard coding the name of those class properties like "OrderName" , "OrderNum" ?

Comment: The DisplayMember and DisplayValue requires string values to identify the property to use in the combobox. Perhaps you could implement readonly properties in your class called `Order.DisplayMember` and `Order.DisplayValue` that return the string to use for the combo properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to sort the combo content afterwards in some way, index actually can be found during `foreach` iteration itself. For example:

```
int currentComboIndex = 0;
foreach(CustomerOrderClass item in cntrlr.ThatHashSet)
{
    comboBox.Item.Add( item.OrderName)
    if(orderCode == item.OrderCode)
        currentComboIndex ++;
}
```

after exit from cycle you will get or `0` or the index of the **last** item equal to specified `orderCode` (that can be `0` by the way), so you can do after the cycle:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = currentComboIndex;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but this will always yelds currentComboIndex = comboBox.Item.Count - 1.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes that was causing to throw an exception, now that is fixed but still has some flows for setting the correct index...I am working on it.

Comment: hmm, shouldn't currentindex be declared to "-1" ? if the item is Not found in the combbox I want its default text to be blank